# Saving Strings to a file

Tags: java, string, swing, file, printwriter

I have a file containing the sentence `Hello World`. I want to make it so that if you press a button and the file contains the word `Hello` it will be replaced by the word `Hi` and if the file contains `World` it will be replaced with `Earth` and vice versa so that the file can contain these different sentences: `Hello World`, `Hi World`, `Hello Earth`, and `Hi Earth`. The problem is that I cant figure out how to replace words in the file but just to override it. So far I use this code:

```
    String command = e.getActionCommand();
    if(command.equals("Switch first word"){
            if(option.contains("Hello")){
                try{
                    fos = new PrintWriter(new File("Options.dat"));
                    fos.print("Hi");
                    fos.close();
                }catch(Exception ex){

                }
            }
            if(option.contains("Hi")){
                try{
                    fos = new PrintWriter(new File("Options.dat"));
                    fos.print("Hello");
                    fos.close();
                }catch(Exception ex){

                }
            }
        }
    if(command.equals("Switch second word"){
            if(option.contains("World")){
                try{
                    fos = new PrintWriter(new File("Options.dat"));
                    fos.print("Earth");
                    fos.close();
                }catch(Exception ex){

                }
            }
            if(option.contains("Earth")){
                try{
                    fos = new PrintWriter(new File("Options.dat"));
                    fos.print("World");
                    fos.close();
                }catch(Exception ex){

                }
            }
        }
```

The problem with it is that one word will override the whole file instead of just replace on word, so how would I make it replace a word with another instead of override the whole file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would I make it replace a word with another instead of override the whole file?

You don't.

You create the four sentences in four different strings.

You open the file, once.  You write the four strings, once.  You close the file, once.

Answer (score 1):

**Probably the cleanest way**

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("filename", true)));
```

The second parameter informs the `BufferedWriter` class to append to the end of the file.

**Alternatively**

You could always read in the whole file into a data structure you create (like an object), then make your changes and write the whole thing back.